# get only date from date time regex

Tags: regex

I have some html response like:

```
<tr>
    <th>new time</th><td id="new_time">2015-07-14 10:18:45 PM</td>
.....
....
  </tr>
```

I  would like to grab only 2015-07-14. Here is pattern I am trying, but I get date and Time. How to I get only date from this?

```
"\"new_time\">(.+)((AM|PM)<)"
```

Comment: `(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2})` would pull the date out if they're all formatted the same.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/dA1gF9/2

Comment: Any luck with this? You have two answers below and two comments here that should help you..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current regex grabs everything because `.+` says `any character`, (.), `one or more times`, (+).

If you want just the date you can do

```
`\"new_time\">(.+?)\s.*?<`
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/pF9kD6/1

This captures everything after `newtime">` until the first white space. You could make it stricter but that should show why your current regex gives you the date and time.

Answer (score 1):

```
\"new_time\"\>(\-|\d)*
```

This works for me

at the end we say

- - = any -
- |  = or
- \d = any integer
- * as many of either of these

Since that does not include the whitespace it should grab only what you want.

Comment: @chris85 Im giving you the the +1 because you method would also take different forms of the date (if they used slashes instead of dashes). Looks like neither of us will get an accepted answer so you may as well get some up vote points.